# Postgres Window Function and extracted/averaged duration between timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Been reading SO for years, but this is my first post. Hoping someone might be able to help me solve this.

I'm new to window functions, but from my understanding, it seems to be what I'm looking for. I've got 3 tables users, tasks and task_users. One or more users can be assigned to a task (through task_users). What I would like to see is a table showing the following:

user ID
user's full name
how many tasks have been issued to that user (occurrences)
average duration for all tasks issued to that user (average_duration)

The current method I'm using to extract a duration for a single task is:

EXTRACT(EPOCH from closed_at) - EXTRACT(EPOCH from started_at)/3600 AS duration

Here are the columns of interest in each table:

**users**
id
last_name
first_name

**tasks**
id
started_at (timestamp w/o tz)
closed_at (timestamp w/o tz)

**task_users**
task_id (references tasks.id)
user_id (references users.id)

Using sql below, I can generate a table showing each user, their ID and how many tasks were sent to that user:

```
SELECT 
    users.id AS u_id,
    concat(users.last_name, ', ', users.first_name) AS u_name, 
    COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN task_users ON task_users.task_id = tasks.id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = task_users.user_id
WHERE tasks.closed_at IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY u_id
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
```

This query shows:

```
----------------------------------
id    u_name           occurrences
----------------------------------
1  |  Mike Smith     | 10
2  |  Dave Johnson   | 5
3  |  George Wilson  | 3
etc...
```

What I would like to generate is the same table as above, but with average duration (hours it took to complete each task) for all tasks sent to each user. Something like the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------
id    u_name           occurrences    average_duration
------------------------------------------------------
1  |  Mike Smith     | 10           | 32.7
2  |  Dave Johnson   | 5            | 15.2
3  |  George Wilson  | 3            | 10.0
etc...
```

I've tried the following subquery and window function, but it's splitting up the users into multiple rows (number of rows showing for each user is equal to occurrences).

```
SELECT 
    users.id AS u_id,
    concat(users.last_name, ', ', users.first_name) AS u_name, 
    COUNT(*) AS occurrences,
    AVG(tsk.duration) OVER(PARTITION BY users.id) AS average_duration
FROM 
    (SELECT id, (EXTRACT(EPOCH from closed_at) - EXTRACT(EPOCH from started_at)/3600) AS duration FROM tasks) tsk
INNER JOIN task_users ON tsk.id = task_users.task_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = task_users.user_id
```

I'm new to window functions and not an SQL guru, but it seems to me that a window function is the best solution?

If anyone can point me in the right direction or offer up a suggestion, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A window function will provide a value for each row. In your scenario, a user has multiple tasks and as such, the join will result in multiple rows per user.

You may try the following approach which modifies your original approach that groups the data by user:

```sql
SELECT 
    users.id AS u_id,
    concat(users.last_name, ', ', users.first_name) AS u_name, 
    COUNT(*) AS occurrences,
    SUM(
        EXTRACT(EPOCH from closed_at) - EXTRACT(EPOCH from started_at)/3600
    ) / COUNT(*) as average_duration
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN task_users ON task_users.task_id = tasks.id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = task_users.user_id
WHERE tasks.closed_at IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY u_id
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
```

or

```sql
SELECT 
    users.id AS u_id,
    concat(users.last_name, ', ', users.first_name) AS u_name, 
    COUNT(*) AS occurrences,
    AVG(
        EXTRACT(EPOCH from closed_at) - EXTRACT(EPOCH from started_at)/3600
    ) as average_duration
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN task_users ON task_users.task_id = tasks.id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = task_users.user_id
WHERE tasks.closed_at IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY u_id
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. Question: does this work because the EXTRACT is within an aggregate function?

Comment: @cndev yes. The expression within the aggregate function will be evaluated first.